# How to add tag property to flutter textfield?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

If I use textfield at Flutter, for example:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration( 
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    hintText: 'Enter a search term',
  ),
)
```

and I want to have tag like I do when I create iOS textField

```
@IBOutlet weak var name1TextField: UITextField!
name1TextField.tag = 11
```

I do not have tag property in Flutter, is there any other way to create iOS tag at Flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this issue, you can achieve similar functionality to the `tag` property of iOS `UITextField` by using a combination of `key` and `FocusNode`.

The `key` property uniquely identifies widgets in Flutter and `FocusNode` is used to manage the focus of a widget. You can assign a unique key to your `TextField` and use a `FocusNode` to associate additional data or properties. Here's an example code,

```
FocusNode name1FocusNode = FocusNode();

TextField(
  key: Key('name1TextField'), // Unique key for the TextField
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    hintText: 'Enter a search term',
  ),
  focusNode: name1FocusNode, // Associate a FocusNode
);
```

With this setup, you can manage the `TextField` using the `name1FocusNode`. For instance, you can listen to focus changes, manage focus movement, and associate additional data or properties with this specific `TextField`.